# Nested JSON not loading as Keys in dict

Tags: python, json

I have the below JSON currently in a dict called returned_data- I would like to get the account ID out, but it looks like it is not recognizing any keys deeper than the 2nd level. eg:

```
returned_data["command1"]["customers"]
```

works

```
returned_data["command1"]["customers"]["acctid"]
```

does not work.

```
returned_data["command1"]["customers"].keys()
```

does not display any keys.

What do I need to do to be able to reference the acctid?

```
{
"command1": {

        "customers": [{
            "city": "none",
            "cust_id": 204567,
            "name_first": "John",
            "name_last": "Smith",
            "zip": "39199",
            "street_addr_1": "1 Bat St",

            "phones": [
                {"phone_number": "(01) 5555555",
                "phone_type": "Mobile",
                "phone_code": "C"
                },
                {"phone_number": "(01) 5555555",
                "phone_type": "Home",
                "phone_code": "E"
                }
                    ],

            "email_addr": "test@test.com",
            "acctid": 123456,
            "state": "WA",
            "add_user": "JR",
            "country": "AUS",
            "acct_type": "P",
                }
                ],
        "ref": "123456",
        "result": 0
            },

"header": {"src_sys_type": 2,
    "ver": 1,
    "result": 0}

 }
```

Comment: `returned_data["command1"]["customers"]` is a list, not a dictionary. Is that sufficient, or do you need to know how to use lists in Python?

Comment: Looks like I need to work my my knowledge of lists- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you'll need.

```
['command1']['customers'][0]['acctid']
```

You're probably getting an index error. The `[0]` is needed because of the bracket after `'customers'`. As the comment said, it's a list, not a json.